# Why the "de" in "d'entre eux"?

Tags: expressions

In the expressions *certains d'entre eux*, *aucun d'entre eux*, etc., is there an explanation why there is a "de"? The meaning seems to be just "some of them" and "none of them", so I'm not sure why it is necessary to place a "de" in front of the preposition.

Comment: Maybe because `of` is said `de` in french? and without the `de`, `certains entre eux` would mean `some between them`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As underlined @oldergod, without *"de"* those expressions would not have the same meaning :

- certains / aucun  = some / none
- de = of
- entre = between
- eux = them

So without *"de"* you have no link between the *quantity* (some/none) and the fact that this quantity is taken inside the group (of *them*).

You would be understood because it is not a big word missing, but it will appear as strange and incorrect - you will probably be corrected.